# Why does this function not return/send anything to main?

Tags: arrays, c, function

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int func ( int[] , int* , int );

int main() {
    int a[10] ={4,2,1}, b = 2, c = 4;
    func (&a[2],&b,a[0]);

    printf ("%d %d %d", *a, b, c );

    return 0;
}

int func ( int x[] , int *y, int z ) {
    z = *x + *y;
}
```

Supposedly the "int func" isn't sending over the new value of z that should be assigned to c. It's just passing over the function and then going back to main with the original values of a, b, and c as originally declared. I'm still pretty new to this, apologies if the answer is staring me in the face.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen to a and b?  The function makes an assignment to z, but not to x or y so it is not at all clear why you think a or b should be modified.

Comment: Now that the code is edited, it seem like you might expect the assignment to `z` in the function to modify `a` in `main`, but you are missing a few details.  `func` may alter its first two argument, since those are addresses, but it cannot possibly modify the 3rd argument since that is passed by value.

Comment: Re "*the new value of z that should be assigned to c.*", No. Nothing copies `z` into `c`.

Comment: You never passed `c` to `func`, so how is `func` supposed to know that it should modify `c`?

Comment: It seems you're missing the basics.  Also, try structuring your question like "I notice that (X) happens, but I'm convinced that (Y) should happen because (state your reasons here)".  If you state your reasons for believing that the code you wrote should have behaved a certain way then we can point out what your misunderstandings are.  You're missing a statement about "I believe the value of `c` should have been modified because...(your reasons)"

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain about not returning any value in a non-void function?

Answer (score 1):

```
z = *x + *y;
```

- `z` is a local variable which stops to exist when the function returns. Any changes to it are ***only*** visible in this function. It is not visible to the external world
- `*x` & `*y` - you only read objects referenced by the pointers. You do not modify them.

In C parameters are passed to the functions by value. It means that only the value of the object is passed and the parameter of the function is not connected to the variable used in the caller.

Also, your function is supposed to return an integer - but you do not have a return statement.

Comment: You may wish to note that a function which is supposed to return a value but has no explicit return value invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Chris Only if the caller does something with the return value. If it's just ignored you can explicitly get away with it.